# Python: Writing a List to a Row in Excel

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to read in data from a text file, create one long string of everything contained in that text file, and split it by space. I'm then trying to send that list split by space to `printStringArray` and have it print to an Excel sheet. I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep track of what row and column the data should be input into.

```
rowNum = 1

def createStringArray(theFilePath):
    theFinalString = ""
    with open(theFilePath) as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            lineToString = str(line)
            theCompleteString = lineToString.split()
            printStringArray(theCompleteString)


def printStringArray(theStringArray):
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook('testingThis.xlsx') as workbook:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        colNum = 1
        global rowNum
        for data in theStringArray:
            worksheet.write(rowNum, colNum, data)
            colNum = colNum + 1
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
```

EDITED:

```
def printStringArray(theStringArray):
    with xlsxwriter.Workbook('testingThis.xlsx') as workbook:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        colNum = 0
        global rowNum
        for data in theStringArray:
            worksheet.write(rowNum, colNum, str(data))
            print(rowNum)
            print(colNum)
            print(data)
            colNum = colNum + 1
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
```

I added some `prints` in to see where I was going wrong, but all the numbers are exactly what I want them to be for `rowNum`, `colNum`, and `data`. Right now it is only printing the very last line.[image]

EDIT #2

```
rowNum = 0
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('testingThis.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def createStringArray(theFilePath):
    theFinalString = ""
    with open(theFilePath) as file_in:
        for line in file_in:
            lineToString = str(line)
            theCompleteString = lineToString.split()
            printStringArray(theCompleteString)
            for aString in theCompleteString:
                theFinalString = theFinalString + aString + "--"
    print(theFinalString)


def printStringArray(theStringArray):
    colNum = 0
    global rowNum
    worksheet.write(15, 15, "Aapple")
    for data in theStringArray:
        worksheet.write(rowNum, colNum, str(data))
        print(rowNum)
        print(colNum)
        print(data)
        colNum = colNum + 1
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
```

Comment: ***"Right now it is only printing the very last line."***: Your problem are that you do `with xlsxwriter.Workbook(... ; workbook.add_worksheet()` for **every** Row of data. You have to do this **only once**.

Comment: @stovfl i moved the add worksheet outside of that function, but now nothing is being written?

Comment: @stovfl it's edited. from what I understand, if I want to write to `testingThis.xlsx`, I must put my `worksheet.write` under it in it's block... but given that I call `printStringArray` more than once, and `add_worksheet` can only be called once, i'm wondering where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attpemt to read a textfile and write the content to an excel sheet, maybe this can help.

I use the [write_row()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_row) function to write a list of strings to a row. This way I don't need to take care of the correct column numbers.

```
import xlsxwriter

#  read textfile line by line
with open(path2txt, 'r') as txtfile:
    lines_raw = txtfile.readlines()

#  remove newline and whitespace on every line
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines_raw]

#  write lines to worksheet, 
#  here we use "write_row()" to write the list of words column by column
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx') as workbook:
    sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row, col = 0, 0
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts)>0:  # only write nonempty lines
            sheet.write_row(row, col, parts)
            row += 1
```